# What could be alternatives in Phoenix for devise and kaminari in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, elixir, phoenix-framework

I've been a rails developer for a while and familiar with devise gem for authentication and kaminari gem for pagination.

As you know, these two gems are almost essential for building a rails web application.

Now, I would start to build a web application using Phoenix.

**Is there any hex to borrow the power of authentication and pagination on Phoenix** like devise and kaminari on Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For authentication you can use combination of `Guardian`, `bcrypt_elixir` and `comeonin`. For the pagination you can use `kerosine` or `scrivener`.

Answer (score 1):

Two battle proven and most solid choices for me are - [Guardian](https://github.com/ueberauth/guardian) for JWT based auth and [Scrivener](https://github.com/drewolson/scrivener) as pagination engine. 
However, in Phoenix both functionalities are quite easy to handle manually without external libs and this is what I would suggest the most.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there have been some structural changes on Phoenix 1.3. You can check [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@tylerpachal/session-authentication-example-for-phoenix-1-3-using-guardian-1-0-beta-a228c78478e6) out for authentication. Also there is this [canary](https://github.com/cpjk/canary) module for authorization. It seems similar to cancan gem in rails.

However, no idea for a kaminari look-like module as I'm also a beginner in Elixin / Phoenix framework.